# ajaxSubmit target being duplicated not replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I have the following code:

```
$('#refresh').click(function () {

    alert($('.report-container').length);

    $('.report-container').each(function () {

        var accordian = this;
        var url = $(this).children(':first-child').val();

        $('form').ajaxSubmit({
            url: url,
            success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                $(accordian).html(responseText);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

this basically gets each of the tabular reports on the page and refreshes them using the form configured by the user.

i would expect this to replace the one and only '.report-container' element with the fragment downloaded from the server. however each time this is ran the call to `alert($('.report-container').length);` is incremented?

this is causing all sorts of issues obv - what am i missing?

ftr i have also tried using the target property on the ajaxForm plugin with the same outcome

I can also confirm that the server responds with one and only one '.report-container' in the fragment so it should be a 1 -> 1 replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you truly only have one container, and it will be replaced:

```
$('#refresh').click(function() {
    var container = $('.report-container');
    var url = container.children(':first-child').val();
    $('form').ajaxSubmit({
        url: url,
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            container.replaceWith(responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

IF you wish to expand to more than one, keep/add back the each but cache the select in "accordian":

```
$('#refresh').click(function() {
    $('.report-container').each(function() {
        var accordian = $(this);
        var url = accordian.children(':first-child').val();
        $('form').ajaxSubmit({
            url: url,
            success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                accordian.replaceWith(responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace an element use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

`html()` replaces the contents of the element. So after the replacement you get:

```
<div class="report-container">
    <div class="report-container">

        ....

    </div>
</div>
```